# ogr2ogr does NOT save "styles", say "color", information; how do I get around it?

Tags: geojson, ogr2ogr

I'm using `ogr2ogr` to convert KML to GeoJSON and I'd like to extract style information along with the data.

The bash script I am using is:

```sh
filekml="/tmp/poly.kml"
filegeojson="/tmp/poly.geojson"

ogr2ogrProg="/usr/local/fwtools/FWTools-linux-i686-3.1.0/bin_safe/ogr2ogr"

# randomNum=14089918888
randomNum=`date '+%s'`

# Grab the National Weather Service Polygon (KML) data file, using SH script in Linux:
getFromURL="http://www.srh.noaa.gov/data/radar/poly.kml?${randomNum}"
wget ${getFromURL}
echo y | mv poly.kml\?${randomNum}  ${filekml}

#-- use OGR program above to convert the downloaded KML file to geoJSON format
rm -f ${filegeojson}
$ogr2ogrProg -f "GeoJSON"  ${filegeojson}  ${filekml} -nln sr_polygon

# ---- examine the KML file and its' sister geoJSON file
vi /tmp/poly.kml /tmp/poly.geojson
```

You will notice KML contains lines like these:

==> color  ffa9a9a9 
==> scale  0.5 
==> href   http://www.srh.noaa.gov/ridge/graphics/FFW.gif

BUT--- geo JSON file has absolutely NO information on STYLE (that was embedded in KML).

Comment: Check first what attributes GDAL finds from KML with `ogrinfo -al -so /tmp/poly.kml`

Comment: there is no standard implementation of style in geojson format. Some applications however will use css to store it. Obviously, ogr2ogr do not have geojson style implemented.

Comment: Let me re-word/clarify that, I'm interested in the style info contained with the KML file itself.
ogrinfo does show 'one' style, but not the one I'm after, within the data-file.
The data looks like this within the KML:
<Placemark>
<Style>
<geomScale>0.7</geomScale>
<lableScale>0.7</lableScale>
<IconStyle id="khIconStyle791">
<color>ffa9a9a9</color>
<scale>0.5</scale>
<Icon>
<href>http://server/FFW.gif</href>
</Icon>
</IconStyle>
</Style>
 <Point>
 <coordinates>
-107.79,46.87,25
 </coordinates>
 </Point>
<name>FFW</name>
 <description><![CDATA[
FLOOD STATEMENT
$$
]]></description>
</Placemark>